# Hierarchies and levels (Pentaho schema workbench)?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, star-schema

I'm new in BI world and I have a lot of questions. I have to do a BI home work project, so I decided to use:

- MYSQL (database)
- Pentaho Kettle (ETL)
- Pentaho schema workbench (star schema)
- QlikView (reporting)

I have a dimension table which is `SUPERMARKET` and it's edited from a connection between schema workbench and MySQL database:

- Table `SUPERMARKET (id_supermarket, name_supermarket, number_of_boxes, active (YES or NOT), date_of_update)`
- the `SUPERMARKET` table is attached directly to Fact table `SALES` by a foreign key.

So my question is how I can establish hierarchies and levels in SUPERMARKET dimension?

What I know is all members of a dimension table must have a relation between them like time dimension (year contains quarter, quarter contains month, month contains week, week contains day).

I have another question: Pentaho workbench export the star schema as a XML file, so how I can call or use this schema in Pentaho Kettle for ETL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First advise: Use [Saiku CE](http://community.meteorite.bi/) instead of QlikView for reporting. It is best choice for querying Mondrian OLAP, creating simple reports and quick testing.

- Reporting tool: Saiku 2.6
- OLAP schema: Mondrian 3.8
- OLAP schema tool: Pentaho Schema Workbench
- Data warehouse (or DB): MySQL
- ETL tool: Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle)

Lets describe the whole concept of solution:

1. **[SOURCE DB]:** You have some data sources (databases, other systems), which data you want to use for reporting. Lets say you have those data stored in MySQL DB.
2. **[DWH]:** To use the data for reporting, you need to create a data warehouse (in star schema), where you load data from `source db`.
3. **[ETL]:** To extract the data from `source db` and load them to `DWH` the `ETL` is used.
4. **[OLAP schema]:** Build the `OLAP schema` on the top of the `DWH`. It is a XML file used by `reporting applications` to understand how to query the `DWH` data. It contains a definition of OLAP cubes, dimensions and measures.
5. **[Reporting application]:** Is a tool which knows how to query the `DWH` data in the OLAP way (it uses MDX queries on the top of cubes, dimension and measures defined in OLAP schema). You only need to define a OLAP schema location and connection to the DWH to make it work.

Note that you can omit the `source db` and `ETL` if you don't have any source db and the aim is just to prove some functional concept.

For the DWH (star schema DB) you need 3 tables with those columns to start:

1. **Standard dimension table [dim_supermarket]:** `supermarket_key, supermarket_name, number_of_boxes, active, date_of_update`
2. **Time dimension table [dim_date]:** `date_key, day_of_month, week_of_year, month, year`
3. **Fact table [fact_sales]:** `date_key` (INT), `supermarket_key` (INT), `sales` (DECIMAL)

..you can fill the date dimension using [ETL (Kettle) on the base of this post](http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/2010/09/building-a-detailed-date-dimension-with-pentaho-kettle/)

Create the OLAP schema in Pentaho Schema Wrokbench:

1. Set up database connection to your DWH
2. Create **cube** "Sales" on the base of `fact_sales`

   - Create **measure** called "Sales" (pointing to `sales` column in `fact_sales`)
   - Create **standard dimension** "Supermarket" (add table = `dim_supermarket`; fill primary key in hierarchy = `supermarket_key`; add level "Supermarket name" with column `supermarket_name`)
   - Create **time dimension** "Date" (set dimension type to `TimeDimension`; add table `dim_date`; fill primary key in hierarchy = `date_key`; add level "Year" - column `year`, levelType = `TimeYears`; add level "Month" - column `month`, levelType = `TimeMonths; ...)

.. now you have created OLAP schema with one cube, one measure and two dimensions

Set up Saiku to use your OLAP schema and DWH:

1. **Add Mondrian OLAP schema file:** Copy the OLAP schema XML file to `saiku/tomcat/wabapps/saiku/WEB-INF/classes/`
2. **Set up OLAP schema location and MySQL connection to thw DWH:** Edit `saiku/tomcat/wabapps/saiku/WEB-INF/classes/saiku-datasources/test`, set `location=jdbc:mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dwh;Catalog=res:test.xml;JdbcDrivers=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;`
3. **Add MySQL connector:** E.g. `mysql-connector-java-5.1.17` to `WEB-INF/lib`
4. **Run Saiku.** Play with your cube.

Comment: Thank you very much mzy, now i know what i have to do.